# PHP Mysql Foreign Keys

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so let me start by saying I'm extremely new to PHP and Mysql.

What I need help with is the following.

I have two forms a Customer form and a Member sign up form.

The customer form submits to the customer table and it needs to share its customerID column with the member table as a foreign key. I have this setup and I can submit data to the customer table. But i don't know how to auto fill the Customer ID column on the member table (Foreign Key).

The Member Sign up form needs to check if the new member is a customer first if they are it needs to find the Customer ID on the customer table and add it to the member table.

Sorry for the long winded question just trying to best explain my situation.

Comment: `The Member Sign up form needs to check if the new member is a customer first if they are it needs to find the Customer ID on the customer table and add it to the member table.`  exactly.  You can also store this data in `$_SESSION` for a later request (aka the session)  Here is the tip of the day `last insert id` depends on what you are using mysqli or PDO on how to access it

Comment: What did you achieve so far? Or you want us to do the job?